# intellij Junit generate test classes for scala

Tags: scala, testing, intellij-idea, junit

Hi I am using scala with Junit.
Every time I want to generate a test class `CTRL + SHIFT + T` it always generates a java class and I always need to reformat the class and the code inside it.
How can I implement this feature in Intellij? 
I'd like to generate a test class like this:

```
    package combiner.impl

import org.junit.Test;


import org.junit.Assert._

class NextploraWeboDataFrameCombinerImplTest {

  @Test
  def combineDataFrames() {
  }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that behaviour with intellij 2019.2

Answer (score 0):

While generating the test you should select **ScalaTest** testing library. The default template of generated file can be changed in *Preferences | Editor | File and Code Templates | Code | ScalaTest Class*.

Comment: What if I just wanted to add the option to add a JUnit scala template? without overriding the default scala